# How to make a list be skipped if it is an empty set when it is being iterated over

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

Could you give me some advice?

There is a box[a,b] in which the number and number of lists are randomly generated.

For example as follows.

```
box[an, bn] = {{z1, {x1, y1}}, {z2, {x2, y2}},...};
```

Then, I'd like to work the following code.

```
  Table[
 t = Length[box[a, b]];
 list = Table[First[box[a, b][[x]]], {x, t}];
 list2 = RandomSample[list -> box[a, b], 1];
 newBox = Append[list2, aa], {a, an}, {b, 1, bn}]
```

For example, the contents of box[a,b] could look like this

```
box[1, 1] = {{10, {4, 2}}, {18.6, {4, 2}}};
box[1, 2] = {{7.99, {1, 1}}, {10, {3, 2}}};
box[1, 3] = {{9.5, {1, 3}}, {7.9, {1, 1}}, {9.1, {1, 3}}};
box[2, 1] = {{9.5, {2, 2}}, {8.41, {2, 2}}};
box[2, 2] = {{9.5, {1, 3}}, {7.9, {1, 1}}, {9.1, {1, 3}}};
box[2, 3] = {{9, {1, 3}}, {10, {1, 3}}, {12, {1, 1}}};
aa = 10;

Table[
 t = Length[box[a, b]];
 list = Table[First[box[a, b][[x]]], {x, t}];
 list2 = RandomSample[list -> box[a, b], 1];
 newBox = Append[list2, aa], {a, 2}, {b, 1, 3}]
```

This is no error.

However, if there is an(or some) empty set in box[a,b] as follows

```
    box[1, 1] = {{10, {4, 2}}, {18.6, {4, 2}}};
    box[1, 2] = {{7.99, {1, 1}}, {10, {3, 2}}};
    box[1, 3] = {};
    box[2, 1] = {{9.5, {2, 2}}, {8.41, {2, 2}}};
    box[2, 2] = {{9.5, {1, 3}}, {7.9, {1, 1}}, {9.1, {1, 3}}};
    box[2, 3] = {{9, {1, 3}}, {10, {1, 3}}, {12, {1, 1}}};
 aa = 10;
    
    Table[
     t = Length[box[a, b]];
     list = Table[First[box[a, b][[x]]], {x, t}];
     list2 = RandomSample[list -> box[a, b], 1];
     newBox = Append[list2, aa], {a, 2}, {b, 1, 3}]
```

in this case,I get an error.

When Box[an,bn] have some empty set, I don't want to calculate the NewBox of Box[an,bn](here is box[1,3]).

I tried the syntax to skip when t==0 using an If statement, but it did not work.
What syntax should I add?
I'm sorry for I don't explain this well.

Answer (score 2):

Will something like this do what you want? Use `Nothing` so the entry is do not show. Otherwise you will get `Null` there.

```
box[1,1]={{10,{4,2}},{18.6,{4,2}}};
box[1,2]={{7.99,{1,1}},{10,{3,2}}};
box[1,3]={};
box[2,1]={{9.5,{2,2}},{8.41,{2,2}}};
box[2,2]={{9.5,{1,3}},{7.9,{1,1}},{9.1,{1,3}}};
box[2,3]={{9,{1,3}},{10,{1,3}},{12,{1,1}}};
aa=10;

Table[
   t=Length[box[a,b]];
   list=Table[First[box[a,b][[x]]],{x,t}];
   If[Length@box[a,b]>0,
     list2=RandomSample[list->box[a,b],1];
     newBox=Append[list2,aa]
  ,
     Nothing
  ],
  {a,2},
  {b,1,3}
]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is perform normally! I didn't use @.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't dig into the semantics of what you're doing, but you could try `UpTo`. So, replace

```
RandomSample[list -> box[a, b], 1]
```

with

```
RandomSample[list -> box[a, b], UpTo[1]]
```

Comment: actually, aa also have some lists.
but Thank you for your advice!